# PSU and motherboard power up failure

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, boot

My girlfriend's computer is not booting any more. Here is a list of the hardware and the tests I've made so far:

MB: Asus P5QL-E
PSU: Thermaltake Toughpower 600W

First failure: the PC was off, pressed button to power it on, but no sign of life, power LED on motherboard was on.
With everything connected, used paper clip between 15th and 16th on ATX connector, still off.
Detached ATX connector, used again paper clip between 15th and 16th, PSU powered on, with all devices still connected (GPU, 3 HDs, 2 fans).
Turned PSU off, attached ATX connector on MB still with paperclip on it, then turned on PSU from rear button, everything turned on, even the CPU fan, but no boot.
Cleared CMOS, then did the last test again, no boot.

Then I thought that MB was dead, so I bought another one, second-hand tested, same model.
Replaced the motherboard on the case, attached everything, powered on, but no power up (like the other one).
I ran all the same tests as with the other motherboard and I had exactly the same issue.
No power up with power button. If I put the paperclip on ATX connector while PSU is off by rear button, and then I power up the rear button, the hardware goes on, but no boot. The LED on the motherboard is on.

Should I suppose that is the PSU? Or I will end wasting more money? Any advice to resolve this nasty issue?

Comment: It could also be the GPU, unless you tested it separately and know that it's good.

Comment: It may be worth while to get a replacement PSU from a local store. If that does not resolve the issue, you can at least return it. A cheap 600W should be under $40 US.

Comment: The whole thing is acting in a weird way. Without changing anything, it suddently worked until now. I went to turn it on again and it's dead again. I have no clue on what is happening. I will try a new PSU.

Comment: This looks a lot like the question you asked two hours ago, so I'll close this one.